# Java - Best way to scan huge directory trees?

Tags: java, performance

In my music player application which i'm writing using javafx i have problem with amount of time necessary to read mp3 files from hard drive and add it into playlist. I've tried FileList, WalkFileTree, directory streaming and still when I try to process really big music folders perfomance is far from satisfacting. I read some of already existing StackOverFlow discussions about that issue in Java but they were created few years ago so maybe something new and fulfilling came up since then, i hope at least.

Comment: Did you use multi-threading in your tests? I would use one thread for building the list and 1-n threads for reading the MP3 infos.

Comment: @Robert
Nope, I haven't used multi-threading yet at all. Might give it a try if you're really recommending it.